# Special characters on Synology NAS

Tags: macos, nas, rsync, synology

I've been backing up my photos and mp3s from my MacBook Pro to a Synology NAS. Many files have names containing special characters like é and ö. I've been copying them with Rsync, as follows:

```
rsync --delete -av /Users/me/Pictures/* me@DiskStation:/volume1/photo/
```

When I log in via the NAS's web interface, the files and folders are there, with their correct names, and I can access them without problems.

However, when I mount the NAS in Finder, the files and folders show up for a moment and then disappear. And if I try to copy a folder containing files like this, I get an error message:

```
The operation can’t be completed because one or more required items can’t be found.
(Error code -43)
```

In other words, I can't access any files containing a special character somewhere in their name.

Side-note: if the NAS is mounted and I copy files onto it with Finder, then I can copy the files back without problems. So it seems to have something to do with how the files got copied to the NAS in the first place.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: http://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/01/08/set-up-the-synology-diskstation-ds411j-to-support-utf-8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine when I don't use SSH, but mount the volume first and rsync directly to there, like this:

```
rsync --delete -av /Users/me/Pictures/* /Volumes/photo/
```